# Restore OS and files

Tags: partitioning, restore

I had two OS on my laptop: Elementary and Ubuntu 20.04. Both of them had problems due to my old machine. So I used to switch from one to another.
Today I tried to reinstall ubuntu. I wanted to keep Elementary as a backup os. I tried to make a new partition for ubuntu system and separate it from other files. So I pressed Erase disk. Because I was not sure if it what I needed I went back, however now system doesn't see Elementary. Partition is still there but its titled as Unknown.
What to do? How to start elementary or at list extract files?

Comment: Good chance that Elementary and files are gone.  That is what 'erase' means.  Very small chance to get some files back, but stop using that drive right now.  Can see this link, but you need to learn how to use the programs for best results.  https://linuxhint.com/top_data_recovery_tools_linux/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, unfortunately, I have lost my files. Only concern, it should delete partitions if I press "Continue", but I have read description and pressed "Go back" button. Anyway a good lesson.